# How to take into account screen rotation when designing 3D scene?

Tags: ios, rotation, scenekit

I am using SCNView to present 3D scene. When the user rotates the device, the SCNView should resize so that the objects inside the scene still have the same heigh to width (or depth) ratio.. However, this is not what I observe. Everytime the screen rotates to landscape or portrait, the objects inside the screen get distorted. They are stretched in an unnatural way and are definitively not what they were before screen rotation.

How to take into account screen rotation when designing 3D scene?

Comment: That sounds buggy. Distortion shouldn't occur. Can you show screen shots?

Comment: Sounds like you just need to redraw your scene. Easy way is to set `scnView.playing = true` which will continually render your scene. Of course that may be overkill for what you are trying to do, I'd like to think a [`scnView.setNeedsDisplay()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/setNeedsDisplay) in your `viewWillTransitionToSize` would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked the `redraw` option in attributes inspector under View->Mode. that did the trick.